# How to convert a Tableau .hyper File to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tableau-api, hyper-api

I want to convert a Tableau .hyper file to a pandas dataframe.
It is possible to convert a dataframe to a .hyper file, but unfortunately, I could not come up with a solution for this problem.
How can you achieve this with python?

Comment: Also worth asking how to do it via Tableau since it can export csv format data which is easy to import into a dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-time conversion, you can connect to the hyper extract with Tableau Desktop, and then export to CSV from the data menu.

If you want to automate a repeatable process that doesn't require manually using Tableau Desktop, have your data provider supply the data in CSV or another format.

Tableau did not initially provide a public API to read from hyper extracts, just to create them. (Presumably, they preferred that people use Tableau to read from the extracts.)

In late 2019, Tableau released an extended Hyper API that now allows programs to read from Hyper extracts

Still Tableau extracts are usually used as efficient mirrors of an original data source - not as a definitive source - much like a materialized view in a database reflects underlying tables. As the API matures, other uses cases may get more prominent.

Two other options to explore depending on your use case that can let you generate Tableau extracts under program control.

- [Tableau Data Extract API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_TDE_API.htm)
- [Tableau Data Extract command line utility](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_TDE.htm)

Comment: For clarification: I want to avoid creating and refreshing extracts from Tableau Server and automate the process. On Tableau Desktop you can incremental refresh your extract by identifying a specific column. Thats what I want to do programmatically with python given a .hyper file.

Comment: I edited the answer to link to a couple of options that allow you to automate extract creation/refresh without using Tableau server.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is outdated. You no longer need to use Tableau Desktop, you can now read `.hyper` files directly.

In October, we released the new [Hyper API](https://tabsoft.co/hyperapi), which can read `.hyper` files in Python.
 Subsequently, the [pantab](https://github.com/innobi/pantab) library was updated to use Hyper API and is now also able to read data frames from a `.hyper` file. Thus, you can now use its `frame_from_hyper` method to do that:

```
result = pantab.frame_from_hyper(database=<PATH TO YOUR HYPER FILE>, table=<TABLE INSIDE THE HYPER FILE>)
```

If you don't know the name of the table insider your `.hyper` file or if you have multiple tables in your file, you can also use `frames_from_hyper`, which will give you a dictionary { table name -> data frame }, i.e., one frame for each table in the file:

```
result = pantab.frames_from_hyper(database=<PATH TO YOUR HYPER FILE>)
```

Comment: I updated the previous accepted answer based on the new API features. Feel free to improve it

Comment: After getting dictionary { table name -> data frame }, is there a way to extract the dataframe out of it?

Comment: unfortunately can not pip install pantab for python 3.11

Answer (score 4):

Check a [pantab](https://github.com/WillAyd/pantab) library:

```
def frame_from_hyper(fn, table='Extract'):
"""
Extracts a DataFrame from a .hyper extract.
"""
```

EDIT - this function was not originally  implemented in pantab, but has since been added

Comment: the function is now implemented in pantab :)

Answer (score 0):

##### If no knowledge of the schema table names: *(i.e. generic "extract all" solution)*

Then it is possible to use [Tableau's community supported code to query the schema](https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Community-Supported/list-hyper-contents/list_hyper_contents.py) and subsequently extract the tables as DataFrames, one-by-one (into a `dict`) as follows:

Get schema / table names:

```
import pandas as pd
import pantab as pt
from tableauhyperapi import TableName
from pathlib import PurePath
from tableauhyperapi import HyperProcess, Telemetry, Connection, CreateMode, Nullability

def hyperfile_schemas_tables_columns_to_df( fn:str ) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Adapted from source: https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Community-Supported/list-hyper-contents/list_hyper_contents.py
    Retrieved: 2024-02-19
    Source License:  MIT license (https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/tree/main)
    Source Copyright Notice:
        # This file is the copyrighted property of Tableau Software and is protected
        # by registered patents and other applicable U.S. and international laws and
        # regulations.
        #
        # You may adapt this file and modify it to fit into your context and use it
        # as a template to start your own projects.
    """
    res = []
    # Start Hyper and connect to our Hyper file
    with HyperProcess(telemetry=Telemetry.SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU) as hyper:
        with Connection(hyper.endpoint, fn, CreateMode.NONE) as connection:
            # The `connection.catalog` provides us with access to the meta-data we are interested in
            catalog = connection.catalog

            # Iterate over all schemas and print them
            schemas = catalog.get_schema_names()
            #print(f"{len(schemas)} schemas:")
            for schema_name in schemas:
                # For each schema, iterate over all tables and print them
                tables = catalog.get_table_names(schema=schema_name)
                #print(f" * Schema {schema_name}: {len(tables)} tables")
                for table in tables:
                    # For each table, iterate over all columns and print them
                    table_definition = catalog.get_table_definition(name=table)
                    #print(f"  -> Table {table.name}: {len(table_definition.columns)} columns")
                    for column in table_definition.columns:
                        nullability = " NOT NULL" if column.nullability == Nullability.NOT_NULLABLE else ""
                        collation = " " + column.collation if column.collation is not None else ""
                        #print(f"    -> {column.name} {column.type}{nullability}{collation}")
                        res += [{'schema.name':schema_name,'table.name':table.name,
                                 'column.name':column.name,
                                 'column.type':column.type,
                                 'column.nullability':nullability,
                                 'column.collation':collation,
                                }]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(res)
```

Extract each table:

```
def hyperfile_to_dfs( fn:str ) -> dict:
    dfschema = hyperfile_schemas_tables_columns_to_df( fn )
    dfs = {}
    for table_name in dfschema['table.name'].unique():
        print('Extract.'+str(table_name))
        dfs[str(table_name)] = pt.frame_from_hyper(fn, table=TableName("Extract", table_name))
        display(len(dfs[str(table_name)]))
    return dfs

d = hyperfile_to_dfs( fn = '../data_filename.hyper' )
for tablename,df in d.items():
  print(tablename)
  print(df.head(1))
```